# Adding array of another schema/object to mongodb from _id including Joi validation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, joi

I'm trying to build a back-end service for a potential portfolio using node.js, to handle projects posted on the page. I want the application to have a seperate model storing categories, and my project schema to contain an array of categories. This is for the post endpoint.

```
const projectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 2,
    maxlength: 50
  },
  collaborators: {
    type: [String],
    defualt: []
  },
  categories: {
    type: [categorySchema]
  },
  lastUpdated: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});
```

This is my projectSchema. The problem i think is when i try to validate the input using Joi. 'Cause the application works if i only use one category, instead of a category array...

```
function validateProject(project) { const schema = {
    title: Joi.string()
      .min(2)
      .max(50)
      .required(),
    collaborators: Joi.array().items(Joi.string()),
    categoryIds: Joi.array().items(Joi.objectId())
    };

    return Joi.validate(project, schema);
}
```

Is it not possible to validate an array of objectId's this way?

I want to be able to post projects like this:

```
{
    "title":"Test1",
    "collaborators": [
        "Name1",
        "Name2",
        "Name3"
    ],
    "categoryIds": [
        "5b7fa72a393c3c14f04066c6",
        "5b7fa76a7a714121b40f2266"
    ]
}
```

The array of string works, but for some reason it's just hanging when i try to use an array of objectIds, and i don't see any immediate errors...

My post endpoints looks like this:

```
router.post("/", [auth, admin], async (req, res) => {
  const { error } = validate(req.body);
  if (error) res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

  const categories = Category.find({
    _id: { $in: req.body.categoryIds }
  });
  if (!categories)
    res.status(400).send("Category with the given id was not found.");

  let project = new Project({
    title: req.body.title,
    collaborators: req.body.collaborators,
    categories
  });

  project = await project.save();

  res.send(project);
});
```

All dependencies are required/imported, so this should not be the problem

Comment: your posted schema is quite different to your posted validator, for example
`categoryIds` vs `categories`

Comment: @JohannesMerz i use categoryIds when passing the data to the endpoint (in req.body) and then in Joi to try validate the id's, and then in my post route i get the correct categories based on the categoryIds, and pass the complete categories into the db

At least that's what i'm trying to do

Comment: please add your categorySchema as well

Answer (score 1):

if your categroySchema is not in this format:

```js
{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Category", required: true}
```

That might cause your issue. As I said in comment, **you will have to post your category schema as well**

Comment: and I assume you category model somewhere